# SQL query- Different databases with inner join

Tags: mysql

I have two DBs- RATINGSAPP and MIGRATIONDATA.

I want to update a table in RATINGSAPP with some values in a table in MIGRATIONDATA. I am trying to run this query:

```
update r set internal_id = m.internal_id from ratingsapp.hotel03 as r 
    inner join migrationdata.migration as m on r.hotel_id = m.restaurant_id
```

This gives me error:

```
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
   'from ratingsapp.hotel03 as r inner join migrationdata.migration as m on r.hotel_' at line 1
```

But a similar select query works for me and gives proper results.

```
select r.hotel_id, m.internal_id from ratingsapp.hotel03 as r 
    inner join migrationdata.migration as m on r.hotel_id = m.restaurant_id
```

What I am doing wrong in the update query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct MySQL syntax is:

```
update ratingsapp.hotel03 r inner join
       migrationdata.migration as m
       on r.hotel_id = m.restaurant_id
   set internal_id = m.internal_id ;
```

There is no `from` clause in a MySQL update.  You are using SQL Server/Postgres syntax.